# Entity Framework code first with derived classes from System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, directoryservices

I'm trying do build an asp.net MVC application that uses model classes derived from `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. I decided to use Entity Framework code-first approach.

Now the problem is that when trying to create a controller with scaffolding, the model class seems to miss an `ID`. I would think that it should be ok to give the derived classes an `ID` property (with `[Key]` attribute), but the error message keeps saying that one of the base classes misses an `ID` property. Problem is that I can't modify the base class.

This is one of my model classes:

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("user")]
public class ADUser : UserPrincipal
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public ADUser() : base(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain"))
    {
    }

    public ADUser(PrincipalContext context) : base(context) { }

    public ADUser(PrincipalContext context, string SamAccountName, string password, bool enabled) :
        base(context, SamAccountName, password, enabled)
    { }

    public static new ADUser FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, string identity)
    {
        return (ADUser)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(ADUser), identity);
    }

    public static new ADUser FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, string identity)
    {
        return (ADUser)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(ADUser), identityType, identity);
    }
}
```

And this is the error message when trying to create a controller with ADUser as model:

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>
> 'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'EF_Hirarchy.Models.ADUser'. One or
>   more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> EF_Hirarchy.Models.Principal: : EntityType 'Principal' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> Principals: EntityType: EntitySet 'Principals' is based on type
>   'Principal' that has no keys defined.

First, I don't have a class `EF_Hirarchy.Models.Principal`. My `ADUser` class derives from `UserPrincipal` in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace (which then derives from `AuthenticablePrincipal`, which derives from `Principal` in the same namespace)

Second, my `ADUser` has a property `ID` with the `[Key]` attribute, so what is missing here?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What benefits you have from reusing classes from a complete different domain? If I were you, I would create a POCO of the same structure and have automapper mapping between the two, the AD prinicipal and the persistable one.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I decided to reuse the classes so I don't have to deal with the mapping. Didn't know the automapper tool until now, will give it a try. Thanks!